Spring boot : console H2 not available in tests
I'm writing a pretty simple Spring boot 3.1.1 application with Spring Batch, H2 and Data JPA.
My application works fine when lauching main() method and can access H2 webapp console
When launching integration test with @SpringBootTest, it works fine too but... but I cannot access h2-console http://localhost:8080/h2-console/
Here's my test class :
@SpringBootTest
@SpringBatchTest
class BankBatchApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
        assertEquals("COMPLETED", jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }

}

Here are my logs when launching test :
2024-04-25T17:37:40.760+02:00  INFO 24840 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb2'

My application.properties in src/test/resources is exactly the same as in src/main/resources and includes this property : spring.h2.console.enabled=true
